# How to use integer literals and arithmetic within Haskell data kinds

Tags: haskell, type-families, data-kinds

I have recently started messing around with `DataKinds` in order to have compile-time scientific units for arithmetic. I have more or less figured out a way to do what I want but I feel like it could be a lot cleaner.

I needed integers that could potentially be negative (m^-1) so I decided to use integers rather than naturals. But as it turns out when you do `:k 5` it gives you `GHC.Types.Nat` which does not fit my needs. I ended up instead making my own custom algebraic integer type. As well as defining addition and subtraction type families to use with it.

But this all seems very indirect, it seems like there is no good reason why I can't just directly use all the existing functions for manipulating data at compile time within type families.

Basically I want the following to essentially be generated automatically:

```
type family (a :: Int) + (b :: Int) :: Int where
    -- Should be automatically derivable from (+) applied to Int
```

Is that possible, if not then why not?

Also is there an easy way to obtain a runtime value back from a type? Specifically when writing a `Show` instance for all these types I basically just want to pull in the phantom type representing the unit combination and convert it to a string. All the ways I can think of doing that right now seem really verbose.

Comment: I don't think this can be done in current Haskell. In a type family definition, we are not allowed to use value expressions (which have a type), only type expressions (which have a kind). Hence, I believe we currently have no way to refer to the value-level definition of `(+)`.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Dimensional](https://github.com/bjornbm/dimensional)?

Comment: "there is no good reason why I can't just directly use all the existing functions" - the reason is that Haskell is not a dependently-typed language. There's a separation between values and types, which means that you have to duplicate code between the two levels and use tedious hacks like singleton values. [The Haskell designers are hard at work on lifting that restriction](http://cs.brynmawr.edu/~rae/papers/2016/thesis/eisenberg-thesis-draft.pdf); in the mean time, you could consider using a real dependently-typed language like Agda or Idris.

Comment: It seems like you are really just looking for dependant types (which as @BenjaminHodgson stated, Haskell does not yet have). "Also is there an easy way to obtain a runtime value back from a type?" In a dependantly typed language, both 'type' and 'values' are simply terms, i.e. there is no distinction. But the tradeoff for more expressiveness is more proof obligation - you will have to convince the compiler of many things you simply consider axiomatic.

Comment: @chi But the following works: `type family Foo a where { Foo False = Nothing; Foo True = Just () }`. So we can clearly use a subset of value expressions, I am just wondering why we can only use certain value expressions.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson But I really want to keep all the things I love about Haskell, plus this was mostly a learning exercise to improve my knowledge of GHC extensions.

Comment: @user2407038 I don't see why you would need more proof obligation, maybe for certain aspects of dependent types but I really cannot tell why you would need to prove anything more for doing what my original question asked, all I am asking to do here is remove boilerplate.

Comment: @semicolon That is because we can lift value constructors to the type level via `DataKinds`. We do not have (yet) a way to lift other value expressions, though. I.e. if we let `n = Nothing` we can't use `Foo False = n` later on. We need `type N = Nothing` instead. Many things can be lifted manually at the type level, but the automagic lifting is far from being universal (albeit it is still very useful, and quite amazing!).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Full fledged dependent types don't seem to be needed here.  This functionality is implementable in C++ which is hardly a dependently typed language.

Comment: @n.m. What do you mean by that specifically? Because the program itself I got working just fine, I just wanted things to be more concise. In C++ can you really do unrestricted compile time data manipulation within phantom types? I would be pretty surprised if that were true.

Comment: @semicolon not unrestricted, but compile time integer arithmetic is built in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer to this question is simply that you cannot currently do either of those things automatically. Hopefully it won't take too long before this kind of thing becomes possible.

Comment: It's likely to happen soonish, I'd say. Maybe 8.4 or 8.6, unless they decide it justifies a major-major version bump and call whatever release it is 9.0.